# Getting 'Not Found' page in polymer app

Tags: node.js, polymer, polymer-1.0

I'm very new to Polymer. i read this official polymer documentation and downloaded a [code sample](https://github.com/googlecodelabs/polymer-first-elements/releases/download/v1.0/polymer-first-elements.zip) and ran it using polyserve without modifying the code.I  followed instructions given in polymer-project website. I installed every required components but after running polyserve command, it shows a page with 'Not found' text. Please help me. 
I've installed npm 3.3.6,node v5.0.0.,gulp 3.9.0 and bower 1.7.7. All the commands are running fine without any error. I can't understand what exactly is going wrong.Am i missing something?

[Polyserve output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b37DR.png)

Comment: Make sure the default port used by polyserve (3000) is  not busy,you can use polyserve -p 8000 to try other port

Comment: Yes. it is not busy. yet it is saying "Not found". :(

Comment: It is working now . Thanks. Problem was that i was using wrong port number. I should have used port number "3000" in the command line. Now it's working fine. :)

Comment: I post the answer, it can helps someone else, you can upvote it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure the default port used by polyserve (3000) is not busy,you can use polyserve -p 8000 to try other port

Answer (score 4):

Start server and try: http://localhost:8080/components/icon-toggle/demo/

Your folder structure should look like this:
[folder-path]/polymer-first-elements

```
README.md       
bower.json
bower_components
demo -> contents: icon-toggle-demo.html & index.html
icon-toggle-finished
icon-toggle.html
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't say what URL you are trying to access in the browser, but the sample code doesn't have any index.html file at its root, so accessing it there will fail.

There is an index.html in the demo directory, so you might have to add that to the url to access it.

Comment: It is working now . Thanks. Problem was that i was using wrong port number. I should have used port number "3000" in the command line. Now it's working fine. :)

Answer (score 0):

I found I needed to add the following line to the `<head>` element of /demo/index.html:

```
<link rel="import" href="/bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
```

Then view `http://localhost:8080/demo` (note the trailing "demo").